# Implementing a general component for table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a frontend app that I use table a lot in its components. then I decided to write a general component for a table.

first I write a model for each cell in the table:

```
export class MemberTable {
  public content: string;
  public type: string; // type --> [text, html, hyperlink, routerlink, button, hidden]
  public functionNum: number;
  public address: string;
  public queryParams: {};
  public cssClass: string;

  constructor(content = '', type = 'text', address = null, queryParams = null, functionNum = 0, cssClass = null) {
    this.content = content;
    this.type = type;
    this.address = address;
    this.queryParams = queryParams;
    this.functionNum = functionNum;
    this.cssClass = cssClass;
  }
}
```

content: the content of a cell

type: a cell has different types. for example, it can be a link or text or button.

other attributes can have value according to type attribute.

table component :

ts file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MemberTable } from '../../../models/member-table.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lenard-table',
  templateUrl: './lenard-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lenard-table.component.css']
})
export class LenardTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() headTable: any[] = [];
  @Input() bodyTable: Array < Array < MemberTable >> = new Array < Array < MemberTable >> ();

  @Output() function1 = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Output() function2 = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Output() function3 = new EventEmitter < any > ();

  constructor(private comm: LoggedUserBaseListComponent) {}

  ngOnInit() {}


  onFunction1() {
    this.function1.emit(true);
  }

  onFunction2() {
    this.function2.emit(true);
  }

  onFunction3() {
    this.function3.emit(true);
  }

}
```

html file

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table 
    class="table table-hover text-center" 
    style="border: 2px solid #DADADE;">
    <thead>
      <tr class="middle-blue">
        <th *ngFor="let text of headTable" 
          class="lenard-th" 
          [innerHtml]="text">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr 
        *ngFor="let memberArr of bodyTable" 
        style="border-top: 2px solid #949496;">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let member of memberArr">
          <td *ngIf="member.type == 'text'">{{ member.content }}</td>

          <td *ngIf="member.type == 'routerlink'">
            <a 
              [routerLink]="member.address" 
              [queryParams]="member.queryParams" 
              [ngClass]="member.cssClass">
              {{ member.content }}
            </a>
          </td>

          <td *ngIf="member.type == 'hyperlink'">
            <a 
              [href]="member.address" 
              [ngClass]="member.cssClass">
              {{ member.content }}
            </a>
          </td>

          <td *ngIf="member.type == 'button'">
            <button 
              *ngIf="member.functionNum == 1" 
              [ngClass]="member.cssClass" 
              (click)="onFunction1()">
              {{ member.content }}
            </button>
            <button 
              *ngIf="member.functionNum == 2" 
              [ngClass]="member.cssClass" 
              (click)="onFunction2()">
              {{ member.content }}
            </button>
            <button 
              *ngIf="member.functionNum == 3" 
              [ngClass]="member.cssClass" 
              (click)="onFunction3()">
              {{ member.content }}
            </button>
          </td>

          <td 
            *ngIf="member.type == 'html'" 
            [innerHtml]='member.content'>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I wanted to know, if this method is correct?

Edited:

I can use table component in other component like this:

```
this.headTable = ['#', 'Analyzer Model', 'Serial No.', 'Ava. Credits', 'Total Tests',
                  'Passed Tests', 'Failed Tests', 'Adapters', ' '];


this.bodyTable.push([new MemberTable(index.toString(), 'text'),
                                new MemberTable(ub.id, 'hidden'),
                                new MemberTable(ub.base_version, 'text'),
                                new MemberTable(ub.serialNumber, 'text'),
                                new MemberTable('12121', 'routerlink', '/controlpanel/customer/mycredit/1/list'),
                                new MemberTable(ub.totalReportCount, 'routerlink', '/controlpanel/customer/analyzer/info/' + user_base.id + '/test/list', {'select': 'total'}),
                                new MemberTable(ub.passedReportCount, 'routerlink', '/controlpanel/customer/analyzer/info/' + user_base.id + '/test/list', {'select': 'passed'}),
                                new MemberTable(ub.failedReportCount, 'routerlink', '/controlpanel/customer/analyzer/info/' + user_base.id + '/test/list', {'select': 'failed'}),
                                new MemberTable(ub.adapterCount, 'routerlink', '/controlpanel/customer/analyzer/info/' + user_base.id + '/adapterlist'),
                                new MemberTable('Add Credits', 'button', null, null, 1, 'btn btn-round btn-orange btn-xs')
                              ])


<app-lenard-table [headTable]="headTable" [bodyTable]="bodyTable" 
    (function1)="goAct()">
```

Comment: I implemented this method. but is it good or not?

Comment: are u using MemberTable as just a model without any function ?

Comment: This question should be asked on CodeReview instead.

Comment: @JameelM, yeah it uses just as model

Comment: Also, Angular suggests use of interfaces instead of classes for Data Models.

Comment: @MohammadAli I agree with SiddAjmera , if you are using MemberTable as a datamodel , go with interface declaration. Without performing any functions through this class , there is no point of Initializing the values through constructor. That's the only change I want to suggest.

Comment: @JameelM I edited my post. I use data model like that I wrote in the post. then I need constructor.

Comment: My main question is that "creating an obj for each cell is correct or not"?

Comment: For example if I have a 20 * 10 cells in a table, then I have a collection of 200 objects. Does it lower the performance of the app

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on your needs. If you want quick and working solution - this could be enough for you. However to increase reusability it would be better to create for each row type component and add it dynamiclly based on current row rendering. There is also another way, just not to reinvent the wheel - `Data Grids` for example [Angular Material Data Grid](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). Data grids comes with many advantages like `sorting`, `pagination` etc., its plenty more of them, but they are not free.

Comment: My main question is that "creating an obj for each cell is correct or not"?

Comment: For example if I have a 20 * 10 cells in a table, then I have a collection of 200 objects. Does it lower the performance of the app

Comment: Again it depends, for just table (excluding other components) in *ngFor you could have at least 500 objects and still have 60fps while scrolling. However keep in mind that every *ngIf is checked when change detection comes to table. so you could have like 5 *ngIf checks per row. That's why I mention in my answer about creating for each row type component and add it dynamicly so there won't be 5 *ngIf per row, but when you want to reload some cells you would have to reload every cell so it could be a bottleneck for performance, so this place is where `data grids` comes handy

Comment: Excuse me, You said, I should create component for each row, then *ngIf repeat on that row component. I think it does not improve efficiency.

Comment: "However to increase reusability it would be better to create for each row type component and add it dynamiclly based on current row rendering" never mentioned about *ngFor. What I mean is to use is something similiar to this https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

Comment: Maybe I should use diffrent terminology. Instead of dynamically think of programmaticaly add component

Comment: oh, you want to say, I just create row component dynamically once, and use it for number of rows. that is amazing, but I have not any idea about implementing that method.

Comment: Close, think of this like in HTML file you are settings an "anchor" point for template insertion like `<table #insertRow></table>`. Then in *.ts file you have to grab this anchor by `ViewChild` and then iterate through rows and check `row type` and just like in medium post use `insert` of viewChild method to insert corresponding `component` to `row type` into view. Notice that every component that is `dynamicaly` inserting into view has to be declared in module as `entryComponent` as well as in `declarations`. Read carefully this medium article I posted above.